# How do I become a reporter for Tellor?

Tags: oracles, decentralization, tellor

I want to become a reporter for Tellor, but not sure where to begin. Are there any guides or tutorials?

Comment: I think you should consult the documentation or reach out to support there.

Answer (score 0):

To become a reporter for Tellor, you can follow these steps and make use of the available resources:

1. Stake the necessary tokens: To begin, you need to stake TRB or the relevant token on the network you wish to participate in. This allows you to act as a reporter.
2. Use Telliot for automatic reporting: To make reporting more accessible, the Tellor team has developed a client called Telliot. This tool enables automatic reporting, making the process more efficient and streamlined.
3. Utilize the simple reporting frontend for manual reporting: If you prefer to report manually, you can use the user-friendly frontend at [tellorreporter.eth.limo](https://tellorreporter.eth.limo), which allows for quick manual reporting.

To learn more about Tellor and the reporting process, refer to the following resources:

- Tellor Documentation: https://docs.tellor.io/tellor/reporting-data/introduction
- Telliot Documentation: https://tellor-io.github.io/telliot-feeds/
- How to Report with Telliot Tutorial: https://tellor.io/blog/how-to-report-oracle-data-with-telliot/
- How to Install Telliot Tutorial: https://tellor.io/blog/how-to-install-telliot-the-noob-friendly-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are! You can find a comprehensive guide on becoming a Tellor reporter here: https://tellor.io/get-started-as-a-tellor-reporter/.

It includes information about setting up a node and using the Tellor protocol. Good luck!